# Xorg: no signal on external display

Tags: linux, video, xorg, thinkpad

I'm having a problem accessing an external screen through the VGA
connector on a ThinkPad T60 laptop.

Xorg seems to detect the screen, because after connecting the screen
to the VGA connector, I'm getting this from XRandR:

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 2304 x 1024, maximum 8192 x 8192
VGA-0 connected 1280x1024+1024+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 338mm x 270mm
   1280x1024     75.02*+  76.00    75.02    71.01    60.02  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.08    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00  
   720x400       70.08  
   640x350       70.07  
LVDS connected primary 1024x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 287mm x 215mm
   1024x768      60.00*+  50.00  
   800x600       59.86  
   848x480       59.66  
   720x480       59.71  
   640x480       59.38  
DVI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

But the screen shows "no signal" and goes into power saving mode.

Fn-F7 (the ThinkPad T60 key combination supposedly switching screens) also has no effect.

This is what I see in /var/log/Xorg.0.log when connecting the external screen:

```
[3512017.896] (II) RADEON(0): EDID vendor "LEN", prod id 16416
[3512017.896] (II) RADEON(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[3512017.896] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   65.00  1024 1048 1184 1344  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (48.4 kHz eP)
[3512017.896] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   54.16  1024 1048 1184 1344  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (40.3 kHz e)
```

Anything else I should be looking into, in order to troubleshoot an issue
like this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Normally, under these circumstances using the function keys solves this problem: for instance, on my Kubuntu, <ctrl>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> enables the external display (careful, it may very well be a different function key on your pc!). The more relevant question is why this is not immediately recognized. To diagnose this, you will have to post the outpout of `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` immediately after having plugged in the external monitor.

Comment: Thanks, but these hints don't seem to solve the issue, although they may help making the question more precise. Fn-F7 has no effect. I also added the log output from plugging in the monitor. As written initially, the monitor _is_ being detected by Xorg (shows up in XRandR), but the monitor doesn't seem to "see" the laptop at all.